# Problems using Microsoft Graph API in TypeScript SDK

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm experiencing difficulties using the Microsoft Graph API in TypeScript. I've followed the documentation precisely, but when I invoke the getAllGroups method, the code seems to hang at await this.client.api(/groups).get();. Interestingly, when I manually make API calls using HTTPS requests and an access token, everything works perfectly fine. However, it fails to function as expected when utilizing the API client. Here's my code:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
import { Client, ClientOptions } from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client";
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { autoInjectable, inject } from "tsyringe";
import { Logger } from "tslog";

@autoInjectable()
export class Graph {
  private client: Client;
  public constructor(
    @inject("msgraphClientId") clientId: string,
    @inject("msgraphClientSecret") clientSecret: string,
    @inject("msgraphTenantId") tenantId: string
  ) {
    const {
      Client
    } = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");
    const {
      TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider
    } = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials");
    const {
      ClientSecretCredential
    } = require("@azure/identity");

    const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    const authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(credential, {
      scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
    });

    this.client = Client.initWithMiddleware({
      debugLogging: true,
      authProvider
    });
  }

  public async getAllGroups(): Promise<any> {
    console.log(this.client);
    const response = await this.client.api(`/groups`).get();
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Could someone kindly assist me in understanding why I'm not receiving a response? I've verified the required permissions, as well as double-checked the correctness of the clientId, clientSecret, and tenantId (they work flawlessly when manually invoking the API using the obtained token).

When i print the Client it looks this this:

```
  config: {
    baseUrl: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
    debugLogging: true,
    defaultVersion: 'v1.0',
    authProvider: TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider {
      authenticationProviderOptions: [Object],
      tokenCredential: [ClientSecretCredential]
    }
  },
  httpClient: HTTPClient {
    middleware: AuthenticationHandler {
      authenticationProvider: [TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider],
      nextMiddleware: [RetryHandler]
    }
  }
}
```